# Adding nearest point-(features) to attribute table

Tags: attribute-table, proximity, nearest-neighbor

Using QGIS I'd like to add the (10) nearest random points, that I created within a polygon, to a target point and have their distances to said point added to that point's attribute table.
I'd like to do this for multiple target points, but cannot figure out how to do it.

[image]

this is how I'd like my attribute table to look like (used Excel only to visualise).